# ASP.NET MVC - Html.Action not rendering the partial view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

**EDIT: Problem solved! I had no data in my database, so the foreach loop had no model items to iterate through. Upon populating the database, the HTML within the foreach loop is rendering correctly on the view.**

My brain is currently hurting due to this problem I have with my partial view not being rendered within my Home/Index view.

I am trying to use `Html.Action()` helper to call my PhotoGallery action within my Photos controller in order to dynamically populate and return a _PhotoGallery.cshtml partial view.

Here is my PhotoGallery action in my Photos controller:

```
        [ChildActionOnly] //This attribute means the action cannot be accessed from the brower's address bar
        public ActionResult PhotoGallery(int num = 0)
        {
            //In the view, display the latest photos when num is greater than 0
            //Otherwise, display all photos

            List<Photo> photos;

            if (num == 0)
            {
                photos = db.Photos.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                photos = db.Photos
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.createdDate)
                    .Take(num).ToList();
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_PhotoGallery.cshtml", photos);
        }
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to PhotoSocial";
}

<p class="lead">Create an account to instantly share your favourite moments with everyone.</p>

<h2>Latest Photos:</h2>

@Html.Action("PhotoGallery", "Photos", new { num = 3 })
```

Views/Shared/_PhotoGallery.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<SocialNetwork.Models.Photo>

@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="" id="photo-gallery">
        <h3>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
        </h3>

        @if (item.photoFile != null)
        {
            <div class="photo-display">
                <img class="" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Photo", new { photoId = item.photoId})" />
            </div>
        }

        <div class="" id="photo-data">
            <div>
                <div class="" id="display-label">
                    <p>Uploaded by:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="" id="display-label">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.createdDate):
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.createdDate)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="" id="display-label">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.modifiedDate):
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modifiedDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.photoId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.photoId })
    </div>
}
```

Here is the HTML source code that is rendered upon loading up Home/Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to PhotoSocial</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">PhotoSocial</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">


<p class="lead">Create an account to instantly share your favourite moments with everyone.</p>

<h2>Latest Photos:</h2>






        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2019 - Thomas Dam</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the final output, my Home/Index.cshtml and _Layout view have correctly rendered, however my _PhotoGallery partial view has not been rendered.

I have tried `Html.RenderAction()` but I need the model to map a photo to the view. I have also tried `Html.RenderPartial()` but I need to return a Model object. One thing I've noticed, though, is that when I place HTML outside of the `@foreach` loop, it appears on my view!

What is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks guys.

Comment: The behaviour is consistent with an empty list being sent to the partial view.  Have you checked that the list is not empty?

Comment: You are correct. I realised this a couple of days ago. I checked my database and there was no data inside it :facepalm:

Basically, there were no model items to render so the foreach loop had nothing to loop through. So I just added some data and everything worked perfectly.